# Как изменить поведение графика из пакета syncfusion_flutter_charts

Tags: flutter

Flutter. При помощи пакета syncfusion_flutter_charts 19.1.55+1 создал динамический график, но из-за встроенной плавной анимации происходит постоянное искажение графика.
Как отключить встроенную анимацию?

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/charts.dart';



void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  Random r = Random();
  List<_SalesData> dynamicData = [];

  Stream<List<_SalesData>> _getStream() async* {
    while(true) {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
      if(dynamicData.length == 10) {
        dynamicData.removeAt(0);
        for(int i = 0; i<dynamicData.length; ++i) {
          dynamicData[i] = _SalesData(i.toDouble(), dynamicData[i].y);
        }
      }
      dynamicData.add(_SalesData(dynamicData.length.toDouble(), r.nextDouble()));

      yield dynamicData;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<List<_SalesData>>(
        stream: _getStream(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
            return SfCartesianChart(
              isTransposed: false,
              primaryXAxis: NumericAxis(
                isVisible: false,
              ),
              tooltipBehavior: TooltipBehavior(enable: false),
              series: <ChartSeries<_SalesData, double>>[
                SplineSeries<_SalesData, double>(
                  dataSource: dynamicData,
                  xValueMapper: (_SalesData sales, _) => sales.x,
                  yValueMapper: (_SalesData sales, _) => sales.y,
                  name: 'Sales',
                  // Enable data label
                  dataLabelSettings: DataLabelSettings(isVisible: false))
              ]);
          }
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _SalesData {
  _SalesData(this.x, this.y);
  final double x;
  final double y;
}
```

[image: Вид полученного графика]

Comment: Вам нужно не анимацию отключить, а правильно управлять через `Controller`. И, да, вы `Stream` и `StreamBuilder` неправильно используете (из-за этого все так прыгает)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если верить [документации](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/cartesian-charts/series-customization#animation), анимацию можно отключить задав нулевое значение параметру `animationDuration`:

```dart
           return SfCartesianChart(
              isTransposed: false,
              primaryXAxis: NumericAxis(
                isVisible: false,
              ),
              tooltipBehavior: TooltipBehavior(enable: false),
              series: <ChartSeries<_SalesData, double>>[
                SplineSeries<_SalesData, double>(
                  dataSource: dynamicData,
                  xValueMapper: (_SalesData sales, _) => sales.x,
                  yValueMapper: (_SalesData sales, _) => sales.y,
                  name: 'Sales',
                  // Duration of series animation
                  animationDuration: 0
                  // Enable data label
                  dataLabelSettings: DataLabelSettings(isVisible: false))
              ]);
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает :)